# Android build from command line in Windows

Tags: android, ant

I would like to build an Android project from command line instead of using Eclipse. I have installed ant on my Windows Vista, and I would like to run `ant release` but I can't find the file `build.xml` in the root directory of my Android project.

The project has been created using Eclipse. Is there a particular reason why the file `build.xml` doesn't exist ? How to find/generate it please ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to make the build file yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this doc wrt how to update an Android project:

https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html